# Rails 4.1 serialization of session

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4.1.rc2. It's the soon going to be launched Rails 4.1 there has been a change with the ways sessions are serialized now [commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13945#issuecomment-34090370) here and [link to guide](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/guides/source/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.md#cookies-serializer).

I am no more able to store my object in the session eq

`session[:user] = User.new`

when i access `session[:user]` i get a `String`.

Any way to revert back to old one ? Or store object in Rails 4.1 session

Comment: I just want to mention that is is a bad idea to store complex objects like a ActiveRecord model into the session. It is preferred to just store the id in the session and reload the object from the database.

Answer (score 1):

```rb
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
helper_method :session_user
def session_user
  @session_user ||= Marshal.load(session[:user])
end

def set_session_user(user)
  session[:user] = Marshal.dump(user)
end

# set
set_session_user(User.new)

# reconstitute and perform operation
session_user.awesome = 'rad'
session_user.save!
```

see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Marshal.html